# I don't get GPS location updates. What am I missing?

Tags: ios

I don't get GPS location updates. I'm using an iPad2 to run the code. This is my code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

        //location
        locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease]; // Create new instance of locMgr
        locationManager.delegate = self;

        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        NSLog(@"locationManager startUpdatingLocation"); //this core runs correctly

...
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
 }


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    location = [newLocation description];
    NSLog(@"new location: %@", location); //never printed   
}
```

Should I allow location in the preferences ? I was expecting the iPad asking permissions for to share the location but I didn't get any.

thanks

Comment: If it does'nt ask for permissions automatically, then you should have already tried allowing location in the preferences...If even that does'nt work then it's something hidden because your code looks fine

Comment: @tipycalFlow I'm running the app from xCode so I don't have the app in the preferences. I mean, there is no way to enable/disable location permissions in the preferences for this app. (the global one is enabled).

Comment: Should I add lines of code to register for location notifications in my app Delegate ? I don't get it..

Comment: try writing `NSLog(@"new location: %@", [newLocation description]);` let me know if this also does'nt print anything

Comment: @tipycalFlow The same... it seems that didUpdateToLocation method is never invoked.

Comment: @tipycalFlow Yeah I've used it, I confirm: the method is never invoked. (and the locationManager is correctly initialized and configured). Is because I'm testing in a close environment ? I've tried nearby a window to see if the gps work :) but nothing to do.

Comment: If everything is properly initialised, then the problem is not in your code but in your device. Do turn on the "locations services" in the settings of your device.

Comment: @tipycalFlow it is enabled and it works for the other apps. I dunno what to do, I've uninstalled the app and xCode reinstall it.. still nothing. Device rebooted.

Comment: hard to tell dude... starting a bounty might help...add all the details you've shared here to your question for everyone to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually removed autorelease and added release in dealloc, and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Is `locationManager` a retain property?  If not, make it one and add `self.` in front of the alloc+init line so the locationManager isn't released at the end of that method:

```
self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Also add `[locationManager release];` in the `dealloc`.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. The problem was indeed about memory management, but the solution was even simpler.